# Emulating 4.0 (API 14) no longer works

Tags: android, android-studio, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

After updating my android development environment I've hit a giant snag. emulating android 4.0 no longer seems to work it will open the emulator window but only display a black screen inside the skin. 4.0 worked perfectly 2 days ago when I was still using eclipse, but after switching to android studio it no longer starts and displays this log on start up

[image]

at first I believed the issue was due to arm-v7a which never used to hinder me before, but I can still start 4.1.2 and 4.4.2 just fine using arm-v7a

anybody got any tips on what might be causing or the fixing of this issue? this is my settings for the device, I am using an intel i7-4770k and gtx 780

[image]

Comment: Just looked up genymotion, and while I dislike using 3rd party devices to begin with, it doesn't even have 4.0, it's priced, and would appear to restrict my access via the adb shell.